# How to convert %02d:%02d:%02d in to double?

Tags: java, android

I am setting time on a `TextView` using

```
Min_txtvw.setText(String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec));
```

Now
`average=distance*60*60/seconds` // my function for finding average
for seconds i have to get time from Min_txtvw 
I done it like below but it gives `NumberformatException`,

```
    try {

             String s = Min_txtvw.getText().toString();
             double d = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();
             System.out.println("average distance is"+d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How i convert that `TextView` value and convert it in double ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NumberformatException` because your variable S contains ":" String value, you need to replace those values by using `replaceAll()` method.

Try following way,

```
try {
         String s = Min_txtvw.getText().toString();
         s.replaceAll ( ":","" );
         double d = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();
         System.out.println("average distance is"+d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: After this line `String s = Min_txtvw.getText().toString();` put `System.out.println ( s );` and tell me what it shows

Comment: 04-25 12:02:25.841: I/System.out(12690): values of s is 00:01:18
04-25 12:02:25.841: I/System.out(12690): formatted value of s is  00:01:18

Comment: O_o, i suggest better you convert it in Time, so that you can get long value of it. The other long way can be fetch the hour,minute, and multiply by 60 and then you will get seconds.